# How to force browser to trust a self-signed cert

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome, firefox

In our Intranet. we have a site (https://site1) configured with SSL using a generated certificate for a different site URL (https://site2).

Chrome/FF/IE/Edge browsers are showing invalid certificate error messages.

**Error message on Chrome:**

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   my.pod6.people.test.com (for example, passwords, messages, or
>   credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>
> Automatically send some system information and page content to Google
>   to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy Back to
>   safetyHIDE ADVANCED This server could not prove that it is
>   my.pod6.people.test.com; its security certificate is not
>   trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a
>   misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection. Learn
>   more.
>
> Proceed to my.pod6.people.test.com (unsafe)

**Error message on Firefox:**

> https://my.pod6.people.test.com/
>
> Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized.
>
> HTTP Strict Transport Security: false HTTP Public Key Pinning: false
>
> Certificate chain:
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> certificate
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

How do I get these browsers to trust my site's SSL certificate and ignore the error in the future?

I tried adding the site certificate to Windows Trusted Root Certificate store, is that the right place?

[image: Add to root CA]

Comment: Apart from the missing details requested by @OscarAkaElvis - Firefox does not use the Windows CA store, i.e. you need to add it to the Firefox trust store too. Chrome instead uses the same trust store as Edge. Please check also that your self-signed certificate is really a CA certificate, i.e. has CA true in basic constraints.

Comment: if you google "How to force browser to trust a self-signed cert" I get a lot of hits. I think you just needed to add that one detail.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, are you adding the self-signing CA root cert you will be using to sign other certs with?   That's what needs to go in the "Trusted CA" store.  The self-signed "leaf" cert you want the browser to trust doesn't go there.

"Trusted Root CAs" that you have highlighted is where to put the public key of the *Certificate Authority* (e.g. LetsEncrypt, Verisign, your in-house signing CA being used...)  If you are going to be your own CA and sign your own certs, and want your system to trust those, you need to put your *CA public key* there.

From your description though, it sounds like you got a site cert *signed by* some existing CA, and you want your browsers to trust it.

In that case, you are putting it in the wrong place.  You want either "Personal" or "Trusted publishers" but that's still just for the OS to trust it.  As @Steffen Ullrich commented above, you will also need to add your self-signing CA's public key to the *browsers* trustStore to do what you probably want.

Comment: I think, he tried to install a copy of server cert in Trusted Root CAs store. Though, the cert might not be self-signed. I noticed this on SE boards, that many OPs call any certificate self-signed..like "got self-signed cert from XYZ", for example. Just because they heard this term..without putting any meaning in it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the SSL is not from any CA - it's generated by ourselves. I'm trying to force the browsers to trust this certificates.

Comment: @Crypt32 yeah people mislead the term *self-signed*. If they got it self-signed from XYZ then it's not self.